# jquery inArray on array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I got a jquery function :

```
$.extend({
    distinct : function(anArray) {
        var result = [];
        $.each(anArray, function(i,v){
            if ($.inArray([v.key, v.value], result) == -1) result.push([v.key, v.value]);
        });
        return result;
    }
});
```

I want to get unique [key,value] on the `anArray` array.

But the `$.inArray([v.key, v.value], result)` always returns -1, so at the end I always have all the values in result array.

What's wrong ?

Comment: What is example input and what is expected output?

Comment: So anArray is an array of objects?

Comment: Yes anArray is an object with some values, like key and value.

Comment: in result I just want unique [key,value]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is object comparison. See this question for more details: [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/)

In javascript, comparing arrays for equality compares their references, not their contents (same as with objects); thus:

```
[1] == [1]; // false
```

You need to do a custom comparison for both key and value, rather than using `$.inArray`:

```
    $.each(anArray, function(i,v){
        var present = false;
        for(var j in result) {
            if (v.key === result[j][0] && v.value === result[j][1]) {
                present = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!present) {
            result.push([v.key, v.value]);
        }
    });
```